# using api with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use API with python but I don't  know where is the problem on my code

```
import urllib.request

api_key = '0275af803ebea3354695c28f9445a842'
#city_name = Batman

def weather(query):
 url = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=' + api_key
 q = query.replace(' ', '%20')
 final_url = url + "&q=" + q + "&lang=tr"
 response= urllib.request.urlopen(final_url).read() 
 json_obj = str(response, 'utf-8')
 data = json.loads(json_obj)

 for item in data['objects']:
    print (item)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Just saying, you don't want to expose your API key to everyone on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to `import json`, and the key is giving me a 404 error. See below for a working example. `data` does not have a key `['objects']` below also print out all the keys of data so you can pick from there.

```
import urllib.request
import json

api_key = '0275af803ebea3354695c28f9445a842'
#city_name = Batman

def weather(query):
    url = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02.".format(query)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

    json_obj = str(response, 'utf-8')
    data = json.loads(json_obj)
    print(data)

    for i in data:
        print("key: ", i, "-val: ", data[i])

print(weather("London"))
```